# making a video full screen using full screen API

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have a video inside a div

When I use this code to expand the video

```
 if (video.requestFullScreen) {
      video.requestFullScreen();
 } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      video.mozRequestFullScreen();
 } else if (video.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
 } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      video.msRequestFullscreen();
 }
```

***The video expands to the browser width and height rather than expanding the whole chrome window to the full screen size.***

> **UPDATE** : This was only happening with my browser ! There was no issue in the code

Comment: Can't you just use `controls` on your video element? That always has a full screen toggle

Comment: I am using my own controls When I press the full screen btn it goes like this (like in the image) which has html5 controls.

Comment: I'd advise using https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/, this seems like a good polyfill.

Comment: I have tried this exactly does the same thing . to the video element

Comment: The demo works for me though. Does the demo work for you?

Comment: Demo works on my browser 
Also when I use only the video in an empty page without the parent div it works but when My own controls mplement in the video it does't

Comment: Ok I have disabled my all extensions but it still does't work
Y'all should focus on the parent div of the video 
I think it needs some css to do something with width and height

Comment: Well your screen-shot still shows the browser's window which is what makes me wonder. For your parent, you should wrap it in an other container, on which you would set the 400*300 style, and on your actual one set it to 100% : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVQKGy

Comment: The problem was with the browser and not the code , The code was error free , Browser was giving issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vh` and `vw`.

```
video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

`1vh` is 1% of the total portview height, `1vw` is 1% of the total portview width. By default, the html and body tags only take up the height that the content does, not the entire screen. Similarly, a page with more than one screen's worth of content will have 100% be more space than 100vh.

`position: fixed;` for good measure so that it sits above the rest of the content in the corner and makes a snug fit.

Edit: Changed "absolute" to "fixed" so it will fit correctly on a long or wide page. `fixed` is relative to the browser, whereas `absolute` is relative to the parent container.

Edit 2: You've changed your question to ask how to make a video fullscreen, not fullpage. The answer subsequently changes.

Here is a guide on accomplishing this; be aware it uses JS and requires the user's approval of the action. You cannot hijack a user's browser.
http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Comment: @Waqas your original question is different from what you want. Review edit 2, I've included a guide that you might find useful.